# Why "Googletrans.Translator" suddenly stopped working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translate, language-translation

I wrote a few lines using Translator function in Googletrans a few days ago. But I was trying to re-run those lines today and it popped a series of errors... I'm really confused by this. If you have experienced similar issue, please comment below. Any help is welcome!!

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
trans1 = translator.translate('Hello', dest = 'es')
```

The error I got is following:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-c0f9e5495a2f> in <module>()
----> 1 trans1 = translator.translate('Hello', dest = 'es')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    170 
    171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
    173 
    174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src)
     73             text = text.decode('utf-8')
     74 
---> 75         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     76         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     77                                     token=token)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    178 
    179     def do(self, text):
--> 180         self._update()
    181         tk = self.acquire(text)
    182         return tk

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in _update(self)
     57         r = self.session.get(self.host)
     58         # this will be the same as python code after stripping out a reserved word 'var'
---> 59         code = unicode(self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1)).replace('var ', '')
     60         # unescape special ascii characters such like a \x3d(=)
     61         if PY3:  # pragma: no cover

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I tried to do research on this error msg, but got nothing. What confused me the most is that this simple code worked perfectly fine 3 days ago. But when i open up this morning, i popped errors. Please help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution below from [this](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/pull/78) link.

Solution:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/BoseCorp/py-googletrans.git --upgrade
```

It worked perfectly for me!

Comment: This also stopped working now in 2022

Comment: As of 2023, this works for me:
`pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1`

Comment: does not some one send an email to the author of this package and notify him/her about this issue??!

Answer (score 6):

Update `py-googletrans/googletrans/gtoken.py` like the following:

```
RE_TKK = re.compile(r'TKK=eval\(\'\(\(function\(\)\{(.+?)\}\)\(\)\)\'\);',
                    re.DOTALL)
RE_RAWTKK = re.compile(r'tkk:\'([^\']*)\'',re.DOTALL)

def __init__(self, tkk='0', session=None, host='translate.google.com'):
    self.session = session or requests.Session()
    self.tkk = tkk
    self.host = host if 'http' in host else 'https://' + host

def _update(self):
    """update tkk
    """
    # we don't need to update the base TKK value when it is still valid
    now = math.floor(int(time.time() * 1000) / 3600000.0)
    if self.tkk and int(self.tkk.split('.')[0]) == now:
        return

    r = self.session.get(self.host)

    rawtkk = self.RE_RAWTKK.search(r.text)
    if rawtkk:
        self.tkk = rawtkk.group(1)
        return
```

Answer (score 3):

Google has changed the way the token is created.
There is no fix at the time of writing.
You have to wait for googletrans to be updated.

Comment: Hi Chris, thx for your answer. Do you know how long normally will it take to get fixed? based on your past experience maybe... Or do you know any alternative packages/functions? Thanks again!

Comment: It's June 2021 and the bug is alive and kicking! How long should I still wait for an update that ? :))

Comment: As of 2023, this works for me: `pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1`

Comment: @Dave: your comment merits being a separate answer, since it resolves the issue as of February 2024

Comment: @essbee: Thanks. This question is closed (due to being a duplicate), thus I could not provide it as an answer. There is a link to the other question at the top of this page. Details of the solution are discussed there.

Comment: as @Dave mentioned:
"As of 2023, this works for me: pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1"
what if this solution stops working, what is the permanent solution for this?