# py_translator stopped working with "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexoutofboundsexception, index-error

```
from py_translator import Translator

translator = Translator()
```

I try:

```
translator.translate("i am a boy", dest='es', src='en').text
```

This used to work a couple of days ago.  Now, I get an error in:

```
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py_translator/gtoken.py

self.tkk = self.RE_TKK.findall(r.text)[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `findall` isn't finding anything, check the code that parses the page, the error is there.

Comment: Where is that code?

Comment: That's what you should post in your question. I've no idea ***where is the code***. Your comment doesn't make any sense. SO isn't a coding site, we're here to help, not to do your work.

Comment: I thought you were referring to code in the py_translate package, not my code. I have posted my python code (just the 3 lines) in the question, which by the way would return 'soy un chico' a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Found the bug and fix here on github:

https://github.com/markolofsen/py_translator/pull/8/commits/410ccdcafdcc2a087b455b4e6a5eb7fef13f1c69

Answer (score 0):

try this:
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
or you can try this
pip install google_trans_new
reference
[googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: Hi Ayush and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please format your code correctly? If you don't know how, here a [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for you