# Text translation with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, translation

I am trying to translate a text column using python which contain different text of different languages  . nothing fancy with my code yet .

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('D:/path', head=None)
```

I used the following code :

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['Text to English'] = df['Text'].apply(translator.translate, src='id', dest='en')
```

but it gave me an error :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I search more for any other code and I came up with :

```
from textblob import TextBlob
df['Text to English'] = df['Text'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x.strip()).translate(to='en'))
```

but it gave me an error of : `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

is there any solution for this ?? and thanks in advance

Comment: How working my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are `None` or `NaN`s values, so is possible filter them by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
mask = df['Text'].notna()
df.loc[mask,'Text to English'] = df.loc[mask, 'Text'].apply(translator.translate, 
                                                            src='id', dest='en')
```

Comment: actually there is no None nor Nan in the text , and still give me the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @MostafaGafer - It is google side problem :( - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456197)

Comment: I tried all of the answers , but I couldn't find any solution for this :( 

Right now i am trying with this code:

import goslate

text = "Hello World"

gs = goslate.Goslate()

translatedText = gs.translate(text,'it')

print(translatedText)

the code is working perfectly and translate the text into Italian,but can you help me on how to apply it for a pandas column. and I would be truly grateful to you

Comment: @jezrael: Do you have any updated solution for this problem? I have a similar problem where I have a lot of blanks and then some entires that need to be translated. But if I use your above solution, it gives me error "list index out of range"

Comment: @jezrael: Were you able to look into my comment? I really need to solve this and totally out of ideas. I have posted a separate question as well if you would like to look at it?

Comment: @Django0602 - hmmm, also fail solution with sample data from question?

Comment: @jezrael: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406660/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0-while-translating-tex this my question. Should we discuss there?