# translate dataframe column with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-translator-toolkit

i want to translate column of my dataframe from french to english.

```
 from googletrans import Translator 
 translator = Translator()         
 df = pd.DataFrame({'French':['ma voiture','Il fait beau aujourdhui']})
 df['English'] = df['French'].apply(translator.translate,src='fr',dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
```

I did these lines but i found an error.. How can i solve it please.?

Comment: Note that in line 1 you miss a comma after `aujourd'` and a quote before `hui`.Moreover, what is the definition of `translator`?

Comment: yepp .. `from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()`

Comment: @sentence  do you see what i mean?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use that package. As suggested by @chitown88, maybe you should try with other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was having an issue with googletrans. But then tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group) that suggests to do:

```
pip install googletrans-temp
```

And your code seemed to work just fine:

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                    French                         English
0               ma voiture                          my car
1  Il fait beau aujourdhui  Such a beautiful weather today
```

Comment: i have always the same problem of ** JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Comment: same error do you see how to solve it .. I did all what you recommand

Comment: you get the same error with just the rows in the dataframe?

Comment: yep with the same dataframe and the same rows

Comment: From what I've been reading, it might be a restriction with google's end. you may need to try through a VPN.

Comment: i didn't understandwhat do you mean?

Comment: the translator works off of googlies api. And Googles server may be blocking your specific request from your IP for whatever reason.

Comment: oh .. And how can i get the translate with other manner please

Comment: not really sure. May just have to find another library or package. I'm not too familiar with other ones. You might just have to search around and see.

Comment: I just tried a different package and got the same error as you. So to be honest, don’t know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate has limits on volume translated. [EasyNMT](https://github.com/UKPLab/EasyNMT) is a scalable solution.

```
from easynmt import EasyNMT
model = EasyNMT("opus-mt")

df["English"] = df.apply(lambda row: model.translate(row["French"], target_lang="en"), axis=1)
```

Comment: please specify a complete example. The above does not seem to work with EasyNMT, but gives `OSError: Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-lt-en is not a local folder and is not a valid model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
If this is a private repository, make sure to pass a token having permission to this repo either by logging in with `huggingface-cli login` or by passing `token=<your_token>``

Comment: Can you please share a data snapshot and the relevant code snippet you are running (helps understand the error)? I believe we are trying to translate from Lithuanian to English here. This is the relevant model on HuggingFace: https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-tc-big-lt-en