# trying to convert a whole column from Spanish to English, with the translate module

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, translate

I'm trying to convert a column containing Spanish tweets (removi stop words, tokenize and stemming process were done) to English with the **translate** module, but it doesn't work for me.

This is the code:

```
from translate import Translator
translator= Translator(to_lang="en")
translation = translator.translate(tweetsCleaned['cleanedTweet'])
print(translation)
```

This is the result that i get:

```
0       andeportes   preocupados   salud   ex   camp...
1       strellaonline   spanama   realidad   crítica...
2       sobresaliente   desempeño   bac   credimatic...
3       sdemontero   migrantes   venezolanos   ciuda...
4       tvcanal8   envideo   presidente   venezuela ...
5       tvcanal8   envideo   presidente   venezuela ...
6       echuguinoscom   bienvenidos   casa   plan   ...
7       tvcanal8   envideo   presidente   venezuela ...
8       cuanto   suele   durar   orgasmo   tortuga  ...
9       edardito   panamá   si   70   juan   diegos ...
10      enanpanama   presentan   programa   pescador...
11      ucusahernandez   importante   gobernador   e...
12      tvcanal8   envideo   presidente   venezuela ...
```

Text still in spanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using translate library 'https://pypi.org/project/translate/ ' and not googletrans then try this (i am not sure about 'es' if it represents Spanish,  but you can change it)

```
translator= Translator(from_lang = 'es',to_lang='en')
tweetsCleaned['cleanedTweet'] = tweetsCleaned['cleanedTweet'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble making it work. I would recommend just using [this](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) instead. Here is the basic use:

```
from googletrans import Translator 
translator = Translator() 
translation = translator.translate("your tweet here")
print(translation.text)
```

Also, the original module has trouble with one sentence words, so install it like this:

```
pip install googletrans-temp
```

Answer (score 0):

**The error is due to a recent change in the google API. A new alpha version of googletrans with a fix was released a few minutes ago.**

Install the alpha version like this:

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

**Important thing to note:**
You have to specify a service url, otherwise the same error still occurs. So this should work:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.com'])
translator.translate("Der Himmel ist blau und ich mag Bananen", dest='en')
```

But his still returns the error (at least for me):

```
translator = Translator()
translator.translate("Der Himmel ist blau und ich mag Bananen", dest='en')
```

See the discussion here for details and updates: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/pull/237

See also this discussion: [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group/65109346#65109346)