# I am using python3 and I want to translate some text, So I used "googletrans" package, but I am getting some error

Tags: python

My Code:

```
>> from googletrans import Translator translator = Transltor()
>> translator.translate("Hello",dest="hi") # "hi"  = in hindi language
```

**But I am getting an error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\YourTranslator\env\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "F:\YourTranslator\env\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "F:\YourTranslator\env\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "F:\YourTranslator\env\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

using python3, pip 2020 latest version
*Thanks In Advance*

Comment: `RE_TKK.search(r.text)` is not returning any matches.

Comment: Shouldn't `translator = Transltor()` be on a separate line? Also, Transltor is misspelled; should be `translator = Translator()`

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change the language? `RE_TKK.search(r.text)` is returning None, so perhaps there's not enough support for hindi?

Comment: Nope getting the same error if i choose french....

Comment: Please show the entire error traceback.  There should be a line of code after the first `File` line, but instead there's another `File`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group
Found Solution thanks god bless you

Comment: try `pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0` should workout

Comment: venky__, Yes I was also saying the same...Thanks BTW

Comment: Does this answer your question? [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: Yes, Tomerikoo this answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alright Guys, I found the answer**

first you have to uninstall your googletrans

```
pip install googletrans
```

And then install this one:

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

**Error solved**
Found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link to an answer as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it works for you, but using **google_trans_new** works for me.

to install :

```
pip install google_trans_new
```

to use :

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator
translator = google_translator()
mystring = "pick your language"
result = translator.translate(mystring, lang_tgt = "de")
```