# Why doesn't Google Translate work when invoked from Python?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to run a very simple Python code that is supposed to translate a word from French to English. The code is as follows.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translate = Translator()
result = Translator.translate(text='Bonjour', src='fr', dest='en')
print(result.text)
```

When I run the code from within the *Pycharm Editor* (using Python 3), it produces an error:

> TypeError: translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

What is wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to replace `Translator.translate(...)` with `translate.translate(...)`. Currently you are calling `.translate` with the Class, instead you need to call from *object* of the class

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion, and I get a new error instead: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: For your second error see [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456197/8106583)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in `Translator.translate(` the first `t` is capitalized an `or` instead of an `e` is appended.

As you can read in the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) `translate = Translator()` creates a Translator instance.

`.translate()` is then a method of your variable/instance `translate` and not of the Class `Translator`

Capitalization matters.

### Complete code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translate = Translator()
result = translate.translate(text='Bonjour', src='fr', dest='en')
print(result.text)
```

Comment: The problem is also that in `Translator` the `e` is misspelled as `or`.

Comment: Yes indeed. I added your suggestion. Thankyou!

Comment: Your code suggestion from above produces this new error: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Can verify. This seems to be some kind of bug in the `googletrans`-package. See [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456197/8106583) As of the documentation it should be working. Good luck.

Comment: Installing this specific version worked for me `pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0` Try it

Answer (score 1):

Now it works -- with google_trans_new:

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator
translate = google_translator()
result = translate.translate(text='Bonjour', lang_tgt = 'en')
print(result)
```

Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: Happy the problem is solved. But please don't reply to answers with another answer. Just [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the best answer .