# TypeError: Object of type Translated is not JSON serializable - Discord.py Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, google-translate, translate

I tried to make a simple translate funcion in my Discord Bot and got to this Error:

```
    Ignoring exception in command translate:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Luca\Documents\Discord\cogs\translate.py", line 30, in translate
    await msg.send(embed=new_emd, delete_after=20)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 904, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 156, in request
    kwargs['data'] = utils.to_json(kwargs.pop('json'))
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 318, in to_json
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=True)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Translated is not JSON serializable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type Translated is not JSON serializable
```

I already looked it up, but i found no solutions. Because it is in the library i don't know what to do about it. Please help me.

This is the code i wrote:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import discord
from discord.ext import commands  

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def translate(self, msg, lang, *,args):
    """Translates words from one language to another. 
    Usage:
    -translate 'language' 'text'
    Language example: 'fr' 'en' 
    """
    #To Check if it has the delete Messages Permission
    try:await msg.message.delete()
    except:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour=discord.Colour(0x1))
        embed.add_field(name="I don't have the permissions to do that!",
                        value="please give me the 'Manage Messages' permission")
        return await msg.send(embed=embed, delete_after=30)
    #Simple Translator | Read on the googletrans page
    t = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'])
    text = t.translate(args, dest=lang)
    #Posts Embed with the Text and also the Language
    new_emd = discord.Embed(title="Broski Translator in " + lang, description=text, colour=discord.Colour(0x1))
    await msg.send(embed=new_emd, delete_after=20)
```

Comment: Can you help us in plain English understand what you're trying to accomplish?  Also, please put the error into the body of the post instead of linking.

Comment: Yeah sure i Updated the Error, I try to get an input from the user where he can say the language and text he wants to translate. The Original Language gets detected and translated in the language the user .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a recurring error in **googletrans** package.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456197/14989571) by @Maldus you can see a work-around to fix this issue.
Or you can try installing the new alpha version which is supposed to correct this:

`pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0`

Comment: I did everything in the post but after that i get a new error... i added it in the post

Comment: You might need to convert `text` to string to pass it to `description`: `description=str(text)`

Comment: Ah nvm fixed it myself but thanks the problem with googletrans is gone!