# using googletrans to translate spanish to english

Tags: python-3.x, google-translate, googletrans

I am trying to use googletrans to translate some Spanish text to English. I am following the examples & below is my code.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
txt = translator.translate('tener', src='es', dest='en')
```

I get the following error though,

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: There is also an ongoing Github issue addressing this: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue is with Google, see the following stackoverflow post:
[googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

This solution worked for me (the accepted doesn't work for me):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65113191/14676920