# why am I getting this group error in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I am trying to create a translator with `tkinter`, `pyttsx3` and `googletrans`. It will translate English to Spanish and talk to you, but I keep getting the following error:

```
code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

This is my code that might be creating the problem:

```
def speaking_sound():
engine = pyttsx3.init()
traslator = Translator()
out = traslator.translate(my_entry.get(), dest='es')
engine.say(out)

engine.runAndWait()
```

Please help!

Comment: We don't need code that _might_ create the problem. We need  you to create a [mcve] that _does_ create the problem.

Comment: Same issue as [googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group).  Try install `googletrans` version 3.1.0a0.

Comment: @acw1668 do you know the command to install that version from the one I already have?

Comment: `pip install -U googletrans==3.1.0a0`.