# Language Translation using Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-translate

I used to use GoogleTrans but this has stopped working with this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I then found this article [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

I then tried to use the version by running `pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0`

However, as I am using Python 2.7 it does not seem to work. I am writing an Agent for Plex and therefore, I am tied in with Python 2.7..

Does anyone know of any translation libraries that still work with Python 2.7??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing google-cloud-translate==2.0.1?

See here under "Deprecated Python Versions"

https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-translate/

Comment: Thanks for the reposnse - but this unfortunately required payment...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this library - free to use and no need to register for a licence or key....

https://pypi.org/project/doodle-translate/

to install

```
pip install doodle-translate
```