# Googletrans AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translation-api, googletrans

I installed googletrans with following command because other versions aren't working properly.

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1
```

I guess this is using old api or something like that because it is very bad at translating. Is there another good module ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: this is duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group.

Comment: No, it justs solves the "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" error. It recommends me to install older version but older versions are bad at translating.