# Python VS Code problem with object has no attribute group

Tags: python

I just started with Python. I had watched a video on youtube about googletrans library, when I tried it on my VS Code, I had this issue. Can anyone help me?
P/s: This is the link to the video that I have watched: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBqLWm47mjM
Thanks all.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQjVC.png

Answer (score 0):

This issue has related to the package release, it is not related to you or your system, you can use this specific version to preventing from the issue: 4.0.0rc1

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

Also, you can find more solutions here:
[googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)