# Cannot use the Translator() function from googletrans module in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I'm using this code to translate the string 'Hola mundo':

```
text = 'Hola mundo'
from googletrans import Translator
Translator().translate(text)
```

But I obtain this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with Python version 3.9 and pip version 21.2.4.

Could someone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me using version `4.0.0rc1`. You can find a list of all versions [here](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/#history).

```
from googletrans import Translator


Translator().translate("Hola mundo").text # Output: 'Hello World'
```

The stable version `3.0.0` returns your error, which is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of Translator to use this API

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate(text)
```

Comment: He created an instance, but didn't save it. However, this doesn't make a difference.