# I get an error when I try to translate something with googletrans

Tags: python, google-translate

I tried to translate something, but every time I get an error.
I appreciate every reply.

This is one of the codes I tried:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

translated = translator.translate("svízelná situace", src="cs", dest="hu")

print(translated.text)
```

And the answer is always the same:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the googletrans package, please use higher version or follow the thread on [github](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/280)

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another version with the fix :

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1
```

Then try without `src` and `dest` language :
[Stack Overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: If the question is answered by another question on Stack Overflow, flag it as a duplicate. These types of link-only answers don’t add very much value.