# I'm getting python google translate "nontype" error

Tags: python, google-translate

My code is bellow and I am getting "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" error what is the reason? (And sorry for my question form I am a newbie at this)

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator


translator = Translator()

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

with open("emre.txt", mode = "w+") as f:
     f.write(pytesseract.image_to_string("01-361.jpg"))

s = open("emre.txt", "r")

if s.mode == "r":
    ceviri = s.read()
    print(ceviri)

result = translator.translate(ceviri, src= "en", dest="tr")

with open("çeviri.txt", "w") as k:
    k.write(result.text)
```

And my error is =

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\usr\amazon_py\çeviri.py", line 20, in <module>
    result = translator.translate(ceviri, src= "en", dest="tr")
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

after the google translate downgrade error =

```
  File "c:\Users\usr\amazon_py\çeviri.py", line 20, in <module>
    emre = translator.translate(ceviri, src= "en", dest="tr")
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 219, in translate
    parsed = json.loads(data[0][2])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: I did and thanks ^^

Comment: As formatted text, not an image.

Comment: No you didn't; you posted an image.

Comment: Post the error traceback as text in the question. Easier for us to read, copy, and doesn't depend on a link that may go stale.

Comment: What does `print(ceviri)` show? The problem is in the depths of the google translate stuff, where a regex doesn't find anything. Kinda looks like a google bug to me. But it may be that you passed in an empty string.

Comment: It's done now ahahaha(really sorry)

Comment: i put a string instead of "ceviri", but the result is still the same

Comment: and print(ceviri) shows a text from an image like "HM...WELL, I GUESS IT DOESN’T MATTER. IT’S NOT THAT"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: nah it isn't work for me. I guess the problem is about version

Comment: pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1

Try updating your google translator. It has some fixes related to unsupported symbols. Which might help you.

Comment: That's exactly what the other thread explained. Have you actually tried to install specific version? `pip3 uninstall googletrans` 
`pip3 install googletrans==3.1.0a0`

Comment: I got new error look at the edit part :D