# Translate a single column to English using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

My data frame looks like -

```
serial_no                                                       text
   23                                  {'Headers': ['LA-Spanish (EspaÃ±ol)[Change]', 
                                      '5790B/5/AF Addendum', 'Secondary menu'], 'Divs': ['', 
                                      'Document(s):5790B/5/AF Addendum (168.88 KB)5790B/5/AF 
                                        AddendumN.Âº de revisiÃ³n:00']}

   25                                  {'Headers': ['LA-Spanish (EspaÃ±ol)[Change]', 
                                       '700HPPK Service Information', 'Secondary menu'], 
                                      'Paragraphs': [], 'Tables': [], 'Lists': [" 
                                       ['Disclaimer', 'DeclaraciÃ³n de privacidad', 'Terms 
                                       of Use', 'TÃ©rminos y Condiciones']"], 'Divs': ['', 
                                       'Document(s):700HPPK Service Information (3.36 
                                       MB)N.Âº de revisiÃ³n:00']}
```

I want to convert the text column to english language. But that column store in a key value format. My code is given below -

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['text2'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)
```

I am getting below error -

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Seems duplicate to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group 
I'm sorry but it doesn't look like it's solved for googletranslator and that users go for other translating modules. You could also try loading another version for googletranslator. googletrans==3.1.0a0 have been working for most users

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 2 problems with this:

- the file has a poor formatting in the dataset, you have a double `[[]]` in the `Lists`
- The translator package give to me the same error, as someone suggested you should try `googletrans==3.1.0a0`, that one worked for me.

Then the procedure should follow start with a preprocess of the data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd    
import ast

data = {
    'serial_no': [23, 25],
    'text': [
        "{'Headers': ['LA-Spanish (Español)[Change]', '5790B/5/AF Addendum', 'Secondary menu'],"
        " 'Divs': ['', 'Document(s):5790B/5/AF Addendum (168.88 KB)5790B/5/AF AddendumN.º de revisión:00']}",
        "{'Headers': ['LA-Spanish (Español)[Change]', '700HPPK Service Information', 'Secondary menu'],"
        " 'Paragraphs': [], 'Tables': [], 'Lists': [['Disclaimer', 'Declaración de privacidad', 'Terms of Use', 'Términos y Condiciones']],"
        " 'Divs': ['', 'Document(s):700HPPK Service Information (3.36 MB)N.º de revisión:00']}"
    ]
}

def data_preprocessing(data):
    # Convert string representation of dictionary to actual dictionary
    data['text'] = [ast.literal_eval(text) for text in data['text']]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    # Normalize the JSON structure within the 'text' column
    df_normalized = pd.json_normalize(df['text'])

    # Remove one level of nesting from the 'Lists' column
    df_normalized['Lists'] = [inner_list[0] if isinstance(inner_list, list) and len(inner_list) == 1 else inner_list for inner_list in df_normalized['Lists']]

    return df_normalized


df_normalized = data_preprocessing(data)
print(df_normalized)
```

Which results in the following:

```
         Headers  \
    0  [LA-Spanish (Español)[Change], 5790B/5/AF Adde...   
    1  [LA-Spanish (Español)[Change], 700HPPK Service...   
    
                                                    Divs Paragraphs Tables  \
    0  [, Document(s):5790B/5/AF Addendum (168.88 KB)...        NaN    NaN   
    1  [, Document(s):700HPPK Service Information (3....         []     []   
    
                                                   Lists  
    0                                                NaN  
    1  [Disclaimer, Declaración de privacidad, Terms ...
```

Then you can explode and properly format the columns:

```
def explode_and_create_columns(df):
    new_rows = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        new_row = {}
        for column_name, column_values in row.items():
            if isinstance(column_values, list):
                for i, value in enumerate(column_values, start=1):
                    new_row[f"{column_name}_{i}"] = value
            else:
                new_row[column_name] = column_values
        new_rows.append(new_row)
    return pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
```

Resulting in the following:

```
         Headers_1                    Headers_2       Headers_3  \
0  LA-Spanish (Español)[Change]          5790B/5/AF Addendum  Secondary menu   
1  LA-Spanish (Español)[Change]  700HPPK Service Information  Secondary menu   

  Divs_1                                             Divs_2  Paragraphs  \
0         Document(s):5790B/5/AF Addendum (168.88 KB)579...         NaN   
1         Document(s):700HPPK Service Information (3.36 ...         NaN   

   Tables  Lists     Lists_1                    Lists_2       Lists_3  \
0     NaN    NaN         NaN                        NaN           NaN   
1     NaN    NaN  Disclaimer  Declaración de privacidad  Terms of Use   

                  Lists_4  
0                     NaN  
1  Términos y Condiciones
```

Finally, you need to apply the translation:

```
from googletrans import Translator

def translate_text(text):
    if pd.isna(text):
        return text
    translator = Translator()
    translated = translator.translate(text, dest='en')
    return translated.text

# Apply translation to each cell of the DataFrame
df_translated = df_final.applymap(translate_text)
```

Obtaining the transled df:

```
  Headers_1                    Headers_2       Headers_3  \
0  LA-Spanish (Spanish)[Change]          5790B/5/AF Addendum  Secondary menu   
1  LA-Spanish (Spanish)[Change]  700HPPK Service Information  Secondary menu   

  Divs_1                                             Divs_2  Paragraphs  \
0         Document(s):5790B/5/AF Addendum (168.88 KB)579...         NaN   
1         Document(s):700HPPK Service Information (3.36 ...         NaN   

   Tables  Lists     Lists_1            Lists_2       Lists_3  \
0     NaN    NaN         NaN                NaN           NaN   
1     NaN    NaN  Disclaimer  Privacy statement  Terms of Use   

                Lists_4  
0                   NaN  
1  Terms and Conditions
```