# I am trying to convert hinglish dataset to english using python

Tags: python, nlp, non-english, google-translator-toolkit

for i in range(10300):
sentence = df["tweet"][i]
translations = translator.translate(sentence.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ASCII'), dest='en')

[The error i am getting while executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcJjm.png)

Comment: Something in your code or in the imported module(s) is attempting to dereference None. Can you also clarify what 'translator' is? I tried this with the standard translate module and constructed translate as Translator(to_lang='en') but its translate method doesn't expect dest

Comment: import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
for i in range(10300):
    sentence = df["tweet"][i]
    translations = translator.translate(sentence.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ASCII'), dest='en')

Comment: This is the whole piece of code i am using

Comment: This appears to be a known issue with googletrans. See:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446811/why-googletrans-translator-suddenly-stopped-working/53577732#53577732

Comment: Actually i am getting error      'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: That's not the point. googletrans is obviously broken. I tried it with a much simpler use-case and it failed similarly

Comment: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on keras-transformers:
Ref: [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/keras-transformer/)

The env.yml file for creating a conda environment is this:
[env.yml on GitHub](https://github.com/ashishjain1547/pubML/blob/main/e12_transformer_based_translation/env.yml)

The manually labeled dataset for Hinglish to English translation is available here:

[Dataset on GitHub](https://github.com/ashishjain1547/pubML/blob/main/e12_transformer_based_translation/Dataset/English_Hindi_Hinglish.txt)

And, the Jupyter Notebook with code is here:
[Jupyter Notebook on GitHub](https://github.com/ashishjain1547/pubML/blob/main/e12_transformer_based_translation/Code/Hinglish%20to%20english%20translation.ipynb)

Here is a blog post for performance report of the same code tested on my laptop:
[Hinglish to English Machine Translation Using Transformers](https://survival8.blogspot.com/2022/10/hinglish-to-english-machine-translation.html)

Comment: I looked at the dataset. I see top 55 sentences have hindlish form of words, rest missing. By any chance do you have hindlish form for rest of the sentences as well?

Comment: As of today, there are now 195 labeled data points. Shall let here know when I have more labeled data points.