# Translate given text by user in Python

Tags: python, string, tkinter, integer, google-translate

I'm using python. There's an entry that with the code `entry.get()` I'm going to translate the sentence that the user types.

```
from googletrans import Translator
from tkinter import *
translator = Translator()
root = Tk()
translator = Translator()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.geometry('300x200')
l1 = Label(root, text='Text (In any language you want)')
l1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=10, y=30, width=280, height=20)
the_text = e1.get()
translation = translator.translate(the_text, dest='en')
print(translation.text)
mainloop()
```

And it doesn't work because of:

```
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

So the error is for the line `translation = translator.translate(the_text, dest='en')`

I have to tell you that I even tried `translation=translator.translate("hermana", dest='en')` as `translation = translator.translate(the_text, dest='en')` and it worked. So the problem IS about this that it can not translate the result of the entry...

How can I fix this???

Comment: The first issue that I can see is that you are calling `e1.get()` just after you create your `Entry`. The user hasn't had enough time to input any text in the entry. Add a button that actually calls `e1.get()` and `translator.translate(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Googletrans module has stopped working for some reason.

See this:
[Why "Googletrans.Translator" suddenly stopped working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446811/why-googletrans-translator-suddenly-stopped-working/53577732#53577732)

Comment: The looks like an issue that occurred 3 years ago. Hasn't the library been updated in the last 3 years or fix this bug?

Comment: I think, no. It's still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the error I see that `the_text` is `NoneType`.
This actually means that `the_text = e1.get()` doesn't work, returns nothing

Comment: `e1.get()` is guaranteed to be a `str`ing or raise an exception if the `Entry` widget has been destroyed.